# Print elements from an ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a class which holds an ArrayList. 
I'd like to be able to print all items from that array, by calling a getOrderItems method in a testClass. I am having trouble, with the way the array elements are returned.

Here is the class:

```
package shopping;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ShoppingCart {
    private ArrayList<Item> list;


    public ShoppingCart() {
        this.list = new ArrayList<Item>(5);
    }

    public void addItem(Item item1) {
        this.list.add(item1);
    }

    public int getTotal() {
        int total = 0;

        for(Item it : list) {
            total = total + it.getCost();
        }
        return total;
    }

    public void removeItem(Item item1) {
        this.list.remove(item1);
    }

    public int finalizeOrder() {
        int cartSize = this.list.size();
        return cartSize;
    }

    //print elements from ArrayList<Item>
    public String getOrderItems() {
        System.out.println(this.list);
    return null;
  }

}
```

Here is the block from testClass:

```
//email possible & create
        int emailPossible = card.verifyCard();
        if (emailPossible > 0) {
            System.out.println("Email object has been added");
            System.out.println("Your orders was successful and has been placed.\nHere are the details of your order: \n");
            System.out.println("Items:\n------");
            System.out.println(cart.getOrderItems());
        }else{
            System.out.println("Email object has not been added");
        }
        //end email possible & create
```

However, my output appears to be printing the address of each item and not the item themselves:

```
Email object has been added
Your orders was successful and has been placed.
Here are the details of your order: 

Items:
------
[shopping.Item@677327b6, shopping.Item@14ae5a5, shopping.Item@7f31245a]
null
```

Comment: either override [Object#toString](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) or acces the field you want to print with a method.

Answer (score 0):

You should override the `toString()` method for the `Item` class. It will allow you to print its objects in the custom way.

Answer (score 0):

Implement toString by overriding object's superclass method in your class and you'll be able to print the list as string and not as reference.